# How to introspect into boost::hana::map<...> when doing SFINAE, without having a (constexpr) instance of it?

Tags: c++, sfinae, boost-hana

Is it possible to check for key existence or even value type, without accessing a `boost::hana::map<...>` object, but instead having only its type? (To perform SFINAE.)

Here's a code, that creates a map of key -> set, and wants to check if set contains an element, without having an access to an instance of that map: https://godbolt.org/z/zOluxI

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename HanaMapType, typename = void>
struct double_key_has_2
    : public std::false_type
{
};

template<typename HanaMapType>
struct double_key_has_2<HanaMapType,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v<HanaMapType, void> // (a placeholder to keep code compilable)

        // detect a boost::hana::map<...>,
        // that has a boost::hana::set<...> under hana::type_c<double> key,
        // which contains boost::hana::hana::int_c<2>
    >
>
    : public std::true_type
{
};

int main() {
    namespace hana = boost::hana;

    auto my_map = hana::make_map(
        hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<double>,
            hana::make_set(
                hana::int_c<0>,
                hana::int_c<1>,
                hana::int_c<2>
            )
        ),
        hana::make_pair(hana::type_c<int>,
            hana::make_set(
                hana::int_c<3>,
                hana::int_c<4>,
                hana::int_c<5>
            )
        )
    );

    static_assert(double_key_has_2<decltype(my_map)>::value); // this should pass

    return 0;
}
```

Or in other words, will all the functions that operate on hana data structures work if passed `std::declval<HanaDataStructType>()` objects?

Answer (score 1):

To use a type as an instance without actually instantiating it, you can use `std::declval<T>()`.

Since you are looking for keys in nested data structures you can use [`hana::find`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-Searchable.html#ga6b6cdd69942b0fe3bf5254247f9c861e) which returns a [`hana::optional`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1optional.html) Monad that can be chained.

```cpp
template <typename HanaMapType>
struct double_key_has_2<HanaMapType,
    std::enable_if_t<decltype(hana::is_just(
        hana::find(std::declval<HanaMapType>(), hana::type_c<double>)
      | hana::reverse_partial(hana::find, hana::int_c<2>)))::value
    >
>
    : public std::true_type
{
};
```

From your example: https://godbolt.org/z/Hv_7_q

Comment: So yes, if I can use `std::declval<T>()` things become possible. It just wasn't obvious to me that `std::declval<T>()` will work. Will that work with all hana functions? Having data objects kind of counter-intuitive when it comes to C++ metaprogramming libraries, since they usually model computations through template/type system itself.

Comment: "Will that work with all hana functions?" Yes I think all C++ functions would work with it because you are only interested in data embedded in the return type. Incidentally there is also`hana::declval(hana::type_c<HanaMapType>)`.